# Azure Logic Apps connector for 3rd party

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to access a folder or files in OneDrive for business that were shared with me. When I browse, I only see my personal directories. And if I try to use custom link, I get

{
"status": 400,
"message": "The file id cannot be a url.",
"source": "api.connectorp.svc.ms"
}

[App Logic Workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTjpx.png)

Ultimately, I'm trying to copy files from OneDrive for Business to Azure Blob Container.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have  you tried using power automate or logical apps connectors?
[MS Power Automate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=41&v=hCuxuUaGC6Y&feature=emb_logo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to say is that we can't input the url of file into "**File**" box of "**Get file content**" action as the screenshot you provided.

Second, according to some test, I don't think we can get the file content which others shared with you in logic app. Because if we use "**Get file content**" action, we can just locate the path of the file which exists in "**Documents**" but can not locate the file exists in "**Shared with me**" path. And the file in "**Shared with me**" tab only exists in others onedrive but not exists in your onedrive.

If you still want to get the file, here is a workaround(without logic app) for your reference(I'm not sure if you can implement it success). If you can see the file in "**Shared with me**" tab as the screenshot below:
[image]

You can use the microsoft graph api to get the file content. You need to request the graph [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-sharedwithme?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http): `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/sharedWithMe` first, and get the `id` and `driveId` in the response of the api. Then request another graph [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http): `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drives/{driveId}/items/{id}/content` with `id` and `driveId` to get the file content. You need to implement the steps in code.

If you can't see the file in "**Shared with me**" tab in page, you may not get any response from the first graph api above. And maybe you can't implement it even if by graph api.